# Django + Angular 5 development setup CSRF handling

Tags: django, angular, cookies, csrf, web-development-server

I am having a bit of an issue with my current development setup when it comes to CSRF verification. Since I am running an angular development server and a django development server side by side and (naturally) need to send requests to the backend, CSRF becomes an issue. Django usually hands the token out when a user connects, but now that the front- and backend are so disconnected I do not get the CSRF token in the natural way.

What I now tried was to add a `@csrf_exempt` decorated function to be able to get the cookie, also by decorating the function with `@ensure_csrf_cookie`. The problem I am having is that still when setting the appropriate header for the request to include the CSRF token, the server still returns me a message saying that the CSRF cookie was not included (bullshit!).

So, my question is firstly how to properly set the header for the CSRF token, this is how I currently do it (typescript below):

```
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {
    const cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
    for (let cookie of cookies) {
      cookie = cookie.trim();
      const re = new RegExp('^csrftoken');
      if (re.test(cookie)) {
        this.csrfToken = cookie;
        // this.csrfToken = cookie.substr(10, cookie.length);
        break;
      }
    }
    console.log('[RequestService] Got token: ' + this.csrfToken);
  }

  post(url: string, body: {}) {
    return this.httpClient.post(url, body, { headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'x-csrftoken': this.csrfToken }) });
  }
```

As you can see above, I have commented out a part of the cookie extraction. The commented part will remove the initial 'csrftoken=' and leave the token itself. Should I trim away the 'csrftoken=' part or leave it there?

Here is the django view that I wanted to use to get an updated cookie:

```
@csrf_exempt
@ensure_csrf_cookie
def get_csrf_token(request):
    return HttpResponse(status=200)
```

The request goes through to the function, but when I manually check the current cookies I have with `document.cookies` I see that it is still the same old crappy cookie which has not updated :(.

I thought about using the CSRF_USE_SESSIONS setting in django to force each request to send an updated CSRF instead, but that seems like overkill for such a simple problem.

Please advise!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer lied in that I needed to set another option on my http request. The request has another option field called `withCredentials` that needs to set to true in order to include CSRF information.

I also needed to substring the cookie I got to only include the CSRF token without the prepended "csrftoken=" which was done in the commented out line inside the constructor where I extracted it.